# Illegal assignment from List<Location> to List<System.Location>

Tags: apex, soql, compile-error, fsl

Here's the SOQL I'm trying to run in my anonymous window, against the standard object:

```csharp
List<Location> locs = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Location LIMIT 2];
for(Location l : locs)
{
    System.debug(l.Name);
}
```

Here's the error:

```
Line: 10, Column: 16
Illegal assignment from List<Location> to List<System.Location>
```

When i search my apex classes, I do not see a conflicing object already named `Location`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error actually crops up any time FSL is enabled in an org. There is a `System` type called [`Location`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_system_Location.htm), and also a `Schema` type called [`Location`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_location.htm). The latter is what you query for, but the former is the default assumed by the compiler, and it is unable to disambiguate.

The fix is to use `Schema.Location` in your type declarations when working with instances of the `SObject`.

```
List<Schema.Location> records = [SELECT Name FROM Location LIMIT 2];
```

Comment: Yup, we have Field Service Lighting enabled - the most poorly documented, poorly acquired-and-absorbed part of the otherwise impressive SF ecosystem